# How do i add textfield value to choicebox?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

```
public ChoiceBox <String> new_make; // 
public TextField model; // 

public void OK (ActionEvent event) { // OK event
    new_make.getItems().add(model.getText()); // choice box new_make  
}
```

my code is here
How do i add model textfield value to new_make choicebox?

Comment: [mcve] please .. and stick to java naming conventions!

Comment: This question isn’t very clear, do you want TextField model to be the ChoiceBox promptText, or the TextField as one of the drop downs?